# How can I hide the file name in full screen mode?

Tags: irfanview

I am using IrfanView 4.33 and I cannot work out how to hide the file name in full screen mode. I want to display a photo but when I do I always see the file name in a bright green font! I’ve looked through the Options and View menus and Googled but have not been able to resolve this so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go to Options -> Properties / Settings -> Full screen / Slideshow -> disable "Show text".

[image]

Comment: "Show text"! How vague! I have looked at this menu so many times and missed that! Thanks.